# Android - How to effectively load large amount of text in EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

I'm trying to load a large amount of text into my edittext. However, the application seems to lag a bit. Text has around 50,000+ characters and around 3000+ lines.

Code:

```
try {
  InputStream is = new FileInputStream(f);
  InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8");
  int c;
  char[] buffer = new char[1024];
  while ((c = reader.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    writer.write(buffer, 0, c);
  }

  reader.close();
  is.close();

  mTextContent.setText(writer.toString());

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Is there another way to do this efficiently?

Thanks.

Comment: why do you need a EditText for such a long text? Are you expecting the user to edit on it?

Comment: is there a reason to store all those amount of information inside a EditText object?

Comment: @Machado this application will basically be used for editing scripts using a phone or tablet.

Comment: Instead of writer try StringBuilder as StringBuilder is a CharSequence

Answer (score 0):

Reading in 50KB of data will take a moment, particularly when reading it in 1KB at a time.

Do not do disk I/O on the main application thread. Please move your disk I/O to a background thread, populating the `EditText` on the main application thread when it is done.

Also, consider using a bit larger buffer than 1KB.

Comment: I've already tried using AsyncTask for this. I placed all the read logic in doInBackground. However, during onPostExecute where I placed the code "mTextContent.setText", I still experience a bit of lag depending on the size. Sometimes I also get the error "MyApp not responding".

Answer (score -1):

Try to append the `string` to the `edittext` at periodic intervals after calculating the `total size` inside this `loop`.

```
 while ((c = reader.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    writer.write(buffer, 0, c);
 }
```

This's just a guess..